# regarding data( ) function in R

Tags: r, tm

When using downloaded R packages, such as "tm", the given example usually loads an example data set such as

```
data("crude")
```

How can I know what exactly this data set is, and in which kind of format, a matrix or a vector?  Only by knowing this kind of information can I customize my input into the format required by this package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from using the help facilities to get more info on `crude` we can do this:

```
# load crude into environment e
data(crude, verbose = TRUE, envir = e <- new.env())

# check what is in e
ls(e) # "crude"  

# what is it?
class(e$crude)
summary(e$crude)

# we are satisfied that its what we want so remove e and load it into workspace
rm(e)
data(crude)
```

In the above case the `crude` dataset contained just one object which was also called `crude` but that is not always the case.  For example, the `state` dataset contains 7 objects and none of them are called `state` :

```
# load state into environment e
data(state, verbose = TRUE, envir = e <- new.env())

# check what is in e
ls(e) # there are 7 objects in e
```

Comment: that is a very impressive answer. Still `?state` does provide information on all 7 data set.

Answer (score 5):

try `?crude`, `str(crude)` and `summary(crude)`.

`?crude` will even get you some literature references.